# New Relic alert when application stop

Tags: devops, newrelic, newrelic-platform, pcf

I have an application deployed on PCF and have a new relic service binded to it. In new relic I want to get an alert when my application is stopped . I don't know whether it is possible or not. If it is possible can someone tell me how?

Edit: I don't have access to New Relic Infrastructure

Answer (score 1):

Although an 'app not reporting' alert condition is not built into New Relic Alerts, it's possible to rig one using NRQL alerts. Here are the steps:

1. Go to New Relic Alerts and begin creating a NRQL alert condition:

   - [NRQL alert conditions](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/new-relic-alerts/defining-conditions/create-alert-conditions-nrql-queries)
2. Query your app with:

   - `SELECT count(*) FROM Transaction WHERE appName = 'foo'`
3. Set your threshold to :

   - Static
   - `sum of query results is below x`
   - `at least once in y minutes`

The query runs once per minute. If the app stops reporting then `count` will turn the `null` values into `0` and then we `sum` them. When the number goes below whatever your threshold is then you get a notification. I recommend using the preview graph to determine how low you want your transactions to get before receiving a notification. Here's some good information:

- [Relic Solution: NRQL alerting with “sum of the query results”](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-nrql-alerting-with-sum-of-the-query-results/52431)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a NewRelic Alert with conditions that check if application available, Specially you can use  [Host not reporting alert condition](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/new-relic-infrastructure/infrastructure-alert-conditions/create-infrastructure-host-not-reporting-condition)

> The Host not reporting event triggers when data from the Infrastructure agent does not reach the New Relic collector within the time frame you specify.

Comment: I haven't purchased new relic infrastructure. Is there any work around that. Maybe through NRQL

Comment: @shasha add metric you can check and add threshold you expect it to return , for example if healthcheck doesn't return after 60 seconds  you assume application is down

Comment: But i dont think that will send alerts

Comment: @shasha add alert that check the metric

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```java
// ...
  aggregation_method   = "cadence"         // Use cadence for process monitoring otherwise it might not alert
// ...

  nrql {
    // Limitation: only works for processes with ONE instance; otherwise use just uniqueCount() and set a LoS (loss of signal)
    query       = "SELECT filter(uniqueCount(hostname), WHERE processDisplayName LIKE 'cdpmgr') OR -1 FROM ProcessSample WHERE GENERIC_CONDITIONS FACET hostname, entityGuid as 'entity.guid'"
  }
  
  critical {
    operator              = "below"
    threshold             = 0
    threshold_duration    = 5*60
    threshold_occurrences = "ALL"
  }
```

---

Previous solution - turned out it is not that robust:

```java
// ...
critical {
  operator              = "below"
  threshold             = 0.0001
  threshold_duration    = 600
  threshold_occurrences = "ALL"
}
nrql {
  query             = "SELECT percentage(uniqueCount(entityAndPid), WHERE commandLine LIKE 'yourExecutable.exe') FROM ProcessSample FACET hostname"
}
```

This will calculate the fraction your process has against all other processes.

If the process is not running the percentage will turn to `0`. If you have a system running a vast amount of processes it could fall below `0.0001` but this is very unprobable.

---

The advantage here is that you can still have an active alert even if the process slips out of your current time alert window after it stopped. Like this you prevent the alert from auto-recovering (compared to just filtering with `WHERE`).